# I believe an electric/gas supply company has forged a backdated letter to me. Is there any way I can prove this?

Tags: fraud, consumer-protection

Currently engaged in a dispute with a gas/electric supplier and applying something called the "Back Billing Code", referring to the company, by law, only having the right to bill me for the year prior to their first letter to me. This has been going on for months and suddenly out of nowhere, they have produced a digital copy of a letter they sent from years ago that I am certain I never received. It's suspicious because:
a. I have never had any problem receiving letters from them or anyone else - reliable postal system here.
b. This is the only letter, in a long period of letter drought, that they claim to have sent (despite having sent me several unimpeded letters since this dispute began - why no follow up to the original?)
c. It has taken them ages to reproduce this letter after a lot of talk about its existence

If I had received this letter none of this would have began in the first place! From my interactions with them I think their ethos would absolutely allow this sort of fraud, but can I do anything about it?

Comment: In the past there have been cases where a supposed copy of an old letter turned out to have been printed in a new font. Its a long shot, but careful examination of the typography and graphics might just turn up something useful. https://www.wired.com/story/meet-the-font-detectives-who-ferret-out-fakery/ . Also, when you say "digital copy", is it a PDF or the original Word file? Either way, check out the metadata.

Answer (score 3):

### I believe in truth, justice and equality for all

What I get is something else.

Nobody cares what you believe: what can you prove? And what can they prove?

They say they posted you this letter. You say you never received it. If it goes to court they will submit evidence about how their internal letter generation and postal system works, this either will or will not convince the court on the balance of probabilities that the letter was posted. If it does convince the court, you will provide evidence of how you deal with incoming mail and that it never arrived, this will either convince the court that the postal service did or did not deliver the letter to you. Then you’ll know who wins.

As to your allegations of fraud: never attribute to malice that which can be adequately explained by incompetence- theirs, the postal service or yours.